Weird overleaf error: Align used inside gather
My code compiles but I am getting error messages. Why?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
  e_l = [0, \mathbf{Emb}(l_{\mathrm{human}}), \mathbf{Emb}(l_1), \dots, \mathbf{Emb}(l_N)] \\
  \begin{align}
    [\hat{y}'^{t}, \dots, \hat{x}'_m] &= \mathbf{Transformer}(\bar{f} + e_l)\\
    [\hat{y}, \dots, \hat{x}_m] &= [\hat{y}' + c_*, \dots, \hat{x}'_m + c_*]
\end{align}
\end{gather}

\end{document}




There is no error when you compile the code. It's just Overleaf thinking that the construction is illegal, which it isn't. You have to live with it, until Overleaf acknowledges that the construction is legal.
This is the output on the console when compiling the example:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./noerr.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-04-11>
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
No file noerr.aux.
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./noerr.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/
cm/cmbx10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/c
m/cmmi10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm
/cmmi7.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/c
mr10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr
7.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy7.
pfb>
Output written on noerr.pdf (1 page, 58878 bytes).
Transcript written on noerr.log.

No error, as you see.

However, due to a long standing bug, \label cannot be used in the align parts.
You can circumvent the bug with a workaround.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\def\alignlabel#1{%
  \begingroup\advance\c@equation 1
  \edef\@currentlabel{\theequation}\ltx@label{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
  \label{A}
  e_l = [0, \mathbf{Emb}(l_{\mathrm{human}}), \mathbf{Emb}(l_1), \dots, \mathbf{Emb}(l_N)] \\
  \begin{align}
    \alignlabel{B}
    [\hat{y}'^{t}, \dots, \hat{x}'_m] &= \mathbf{Transformer}(\bar{f} + e_l)\\
    \alignlabel{C}
    [\hat{y}, \dots, \hat{x}_m] &= [\hat{y}' + c_*, \dots, \hat{x}'_m + c_*]
\end{align}   
\end{gather}

\eqref{A}, \eqref{B}, \eqref{C}           

\end{document}



+1 for posting an answer that's not completely wrong:-)
